# Set Retention Period in BLOB Storage in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to SET RETENTION Period manually so that I can delete my archived data once retention period is over. Please suggest me any link or way which could help me. Please suggest how I will be able to code in my portal to set it.

Comment: Please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blob-storage-lifecycle-management-public-preview/. This feature was recently announced in public preview. HTH.

Comment: Have you already checked the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage#getting-started)?

Comment: IT IS NOW SUPPORTED. You can setup a retention policy(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully configured a [lifecycle management policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=template), which does exactly what you want to do, with ARM templates. Here's the minimal working example:

```
 }
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
  "name": "[variables('storageAccountName']",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_LRS",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "kind": "StorageV2",
  "properties": {
    "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
  "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
  "name": "[concat(variables('storageAccountName'), '/', 'default')]",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "lastAccessTimeTrackingPolicy": {
      "blobType": [ "string" ],
      "enable": true,
      "name": "AccessTimeTracking",
      "trackingGranularityInDays": 1
    }
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies",
  "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
  "name": "[concat(variables('storageAccountName'), '/', 'default')]",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "policy": {
      "rules": [
        {
          "name": "expirationRule",
          "enabled": true,
          "type": "Lifecycle",
          "definition": {
            "filters": {
              "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ]
            },
            "actions": {
              "baseBlob": {
                "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 90 }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, I have setup the search to happen once a day with the `trackingGranularityInDays` field, and the BLOBs to be deleted after 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

Note the approach I mention is not the direct approach of setting the retention duration per blob but a higher level policy which can affect the whole storage account or specific containers or specific blobs which match some filtration criteria. As of March 2021, I haven't yet found a way to set the retention period o  a per blob basis via the Azure API.

[Link to Lifecycle Management for Azure Blobs for Azure Storage V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal)