# BlobRetentionPolicy() how to use it? I need to set expiry days for my azure blob file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account, retention

I'm using this package: Azure Storage Blobs of version 12.16.0.

In order to force the file to be automatically removed from the Azure container, I need to work with Life Cycle policy.

I found this class:

`var retentionPolicy = new BlobRetentionPolicy(){ Days = 15, Enabled = true };`

But I don't know hot to use this with blob class or container class. In which place this class must be used? How to use it? BlobContainerClient or BlobClient classes doesn't have it methods to Set this policy.

I'm waiting to find a method that will allow me to set the given policy from C# code!

Comment: You can send a request.  See following json example which can be put into the contents/body of a request : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952681/set-retention-period-in-blob-storage-in-azure?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng, looks great, but how do I create this request using BlobClient? In theory, this is all fine, I need a specific implementation in C #

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?force_isolation=true&tabs=visual-studio%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Cidentity-visual-studio

Comment: @jdweng, what exactly should I be looking at here? Here the basic CRUD is shown, where in the article does it say how to set the life cycle rule? Or set the other rule?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=template

Comment: @jdweng, u didn't answer for my question, I know how to do this in theory, I need working C# code. I need working code that set expiry days when I upload my files to the Azure `x-ms-immutability-policy-until-date` ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @jdweng comments, you can use [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=azure-ad) Rest Api as below

```
PUT https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
```

> Version 2020-06-12 and later. Specifies the *retention-until* date to be set on the blob. This is the date until which the blob can be protected from being modified or deleted. Follows RFC1123 format.

where you can set `x-ms-immutability-policy-until-date` in your Request body to set the retention policy.

Alternatively, you can manually delete blobs by comparing the dates to check if the blob is created 15 days ago or not as below.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("<CONNECTION_STRING>");
        
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container");

        foreach(BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobs())
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);

            int dateDifference = blobClient.GetProperties().Value.CreatedOn.Date.CompareTo(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date);

            if (dateDifference == 15)
            {
                blobClient.Delete();
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleted {blob.Name} which is created {dateDifference} days ago");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I have set date difference as 0.

*Results:*

[image]

Comment: How to do this from C# code? How to set `x-ms-immutability-policy-until-date` using C# code? I don't need to delete manually my blob-files, I just need to set expiration date when I uploading and that's all